# Is there way to disable "Download" bar blinking in Firefox?

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I like to use Windows so that task bar is hidden. When I'm downloading something with Firefox, taskbar pops up and starts to blink Firefox's "Downloads" bar and it goes away only if you click it. Is there way so this wouldn't happen? Or so that if "Downloads" window already is there it wouldn't blink it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to stop the blinking of the download window:

> 1. Type `about:config` into your browser's address bar
> 2. If you get the "You could void your waranty" warning, uncheck
>      the option to be warned again and tell
>      Firefox you want to continue
> 3. Copy & paste this into the `Filter` bar: `browser.download.manager.flashCount`
> 4. Double-click the item and set it to **0**

You'll need to restart Firefox to let the settings go into effect.

Some other relevant changes you might wish to make:

> - Set `browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting` to **false** to prevent the download manager from showing when you start a download.
> - Set `browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete` to **false** (just double-click the entry once you've found it).  This will prevent that little alert at the bottom of your screen when all downloads complete.
> - Make sure that `browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting` is set to the default of **false** to keep the download manager from stealing focus when a download starts.

Hopefully that should help. If not, you can check out some of the details for other download manager settings (and, well, most of the `about:config` entries) on the MozillaZine wiki pages:

- [about:config Entries](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries)
- [Category: Preferences page 1](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Category:Preferences)

(For some reason that I can't quite grok the details on the `about:config` settings are split up).

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally recommend getting rid of the Dowloads window altogether and installing the [Download Statusbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/26) extension. It puts all of your downloads just above the Firefox statusbar, instead of having them in a seperate window.

Comment: Download Statusbar is excellent; another alternative is the "All-in-one-Sidebar" extension that puts the DLM in your sidebar (along with many other windows and panels).